# Mandatory Event not subscibed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**Problem:**

I am working on a application where in for some time consuming operation, i am supposed to show a progress bar on a form (WinForm) with a cancel button. So obviously i am using BackgroundWorker thread for it. Below is the code which simulates roughly of what i am trying to achieve.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public delegate void SomeDelegateHandler();

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public event SomeDelegateHandler DoSomeAction;
        BackgroundWorker bgWorker;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);
        }

        void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //Some logic code here.
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                DoSomeAction();
            }
        }       

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DoSomeAction != null)
                bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            else throw new EventNotSubscribedException();//Is this a valid style??
        }
    }

    public class EventNotSubscribedException : ApplicationException
    {
       //Some custom code here
    }
}
```

**My Solution**

As per the above code, as soon as the form is displayed to the user (OnShown event) i am starting the backgroundworker thread. This is because, the user need not to initiate any action for this to happen. So onshown does time consuming operation job. But the issue is, as i have shown above, the main time consuming job is executed on other class/component where it is kind of tight bounded too (legacy code: cant refactor). Hence i have subscribed to the event DoSomeAction in that legacy code class which launches this form.

**Doubt/Question:**

Is it valid to throw exception as shown above? (Please read my justification below).

**Justification:**

The OnShown event does check for null on event handler object. This is because, to make this form usable, the event has to be subscribed by the subscriber (usage code), then only it shall work. If not, then the form just displays and does noting at all and usage code may not know why it is happenings so. The usage code may assume that subscribing to the event is option just like button click events per say.

Hope my post is clear and understandable.

Thanks & Happy Coding,
Zen :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you need to throw an exception to the caller of the form? Is it called using showDialog or Show?

BTW, I dont prefer to generate an exception from an event. Rather it would be rather nice to keep it such that it returns from the place with some status set on the Form class.

for instance, I would prefer using

IsEventSubscribed = false
this.Close()

rather than EventNotSubscribedException

BTW, One problem I can see in the code, when the bgWorker_DoWork is called, you should check DoSomeAction to null, because otherwise it might cause NullReferenceException.

Preferably,

1. Start the run the RunWorkerAsync from Form_shown
2. Check Delegate to null in DoWork, if it is null, do not call DoSomeAction otherwise call it.
3. On RunWorkerCompleted of the BackgroundWorker, close the form.

Let me know if you need anything more.

Comment: Well even i do not prefer to throw an exception, because its a costly operation for the CLR. However, in this scenario i am destined to do that because its mandatory to be subscribed. With out the subscription, this whole form is useless to the user or for the usage code.

If you noticed in the code, RunWorkerAsync is called in OnShown event after checking null on the delegate. This way i need not to do it in DoWork (if its called multiple times? then checking is waste), hence i am achiving fail early kinda principle.

Comment: IsEventSubscribed = false this.Close()

Good suggestion, thanks. But still the usage code does not have any idea why on earth the form is closing unless he/she has a code at hand. I even thought of setting some thing for the DialogResult, but nope.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making the consuming code construct the BackgroundWorker and pass it to the form's constructor.  You can do a null test in the constructor and side-step this whole issue.  Alternatively, take the delegate as a constructor argument instead.  I mean, how likely is it that the consuming code will need to change the worker delegate mid-operation?

---

Another approach is to have the dialog *monitor* a task, instead of having a dialog *control* a task (as you have here).  For example, you could have an interface like this:

```
public interface IMonitorableTask {
    void Start();

    event EventHandler<TData> TaskProgress;
}
```

Where `TData` is a type that provides any information you might need to update the dialog (such as percent completed).

The downside to this is that each task needs to be a type of its own.  This can lead to very ugly, cluttered code.  You could mitigate that issue somewhat by creating a helper class, something like:

```
public class DelegateTask : IMonitorableTask {
    private Action<Action<TData>> taskDelegate;

    public event EventHandler<TData> TaskProgress;

    public DelegateTask(Action<Action<TData>> taskDelegate) {
        if (taskDelegate == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("taskDelegate");

        this.taskDelegate = taskDelegate;
    }

    protected void FireTaskProgress(TData data) {
        var handler = TaskProgress;

        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, data);
    }

    public void Start() {
        taskDelegate(FireTaskProgress);
    }
}
```

Then your task methods become factories:

```
public IMonitorableTask CreateFooTask(object argument) {
    return new DelegateTask(progress => {
        DoStuffWith(argument);

        progress(new TData(0.5));

        DoMoreStuffWith(argument);

        progress(new TData(1));
    });
}
```

And now you can easily(*) support, say, a command-line interface.  Just attach a different monitor object to the task's event.

(*) Depending on how clean your UI/logic separation already is, of course.

Comment: Well in that case, seperation of concern and encapsulation is violated. The caller code knows more about the destination object/class and how it works and all. Sorry not an option i prefer for.

Comment: Then accepting the delegate as a constructor parameter seems like the right way to go.  You might also override `Show()` and/or `ShowDialog()`, do the null test there, and pass the call through to `base` if the test succeeds.  However, note that the event might change after the form is shown, so you might cache the value that you tested on a field to prevent it from becoming null later.

Comment: Dont you think even accepting delegate object is a bad design in terms of encapsulation? I mean only they have to hook an handler and not command me which deleagte they want to be passed on.

Comment: Event add/remove methods take a delegate as a parameter.  Either way, you're going to be handed a delegate.  The only question is where you want to accept it.

Comment: The way I have solved the overall problem (a dialog to show progress) in the past is to have each operation be a class implementing an interface that has events, and the dialog attaches event handlers to update itself based on events coming from the task.  This is the opposite of what you have -- a dialog that *invokes* the task, instead of a dialog that *monitors* a task.  Neither approach is necessarily correct, but having the dialog monitor a task may provide an even higher degree of separation, since it does not have to concern itself with how the task is invoked.

Comment: hmm.. sounds like some thing new 2 learn, thanks. perhapsa code snippet please? thanks :)